# Grails 2.0.4 in Intellij IDEA 11.0.2 breakpoints do not suspend, though code is obviously running

Tags: debugging, grails, intellij-idea, breakpoints, grails-2.0

I have a Controller class with really boring code in it. If I go to the run->debug menu and run it, and then navigate to the page that is associated with the controller, no breakpoints will suspend. Period. The red circles have checkmarks in them indicating that I don't have them mistakenly set on non-executable lines. I've done a 'grails clean'. It only affects certain controllers, another with breakpoints will suspend.

All newly created controllers fail to suspend as well.

It has to be a configuration issue in IntelliJ, but it won't seem to budge.

Also happening, no idea if it's related or not: on the sidepanel in the Grails View, it's underlining Controllers" with red squiggles. None of the leafs in the treeview are underlined however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've discovered the problem:

I initially created the project with Grails 1.3.7. Upon discovering a bug that was still unfixed, I upgraded to 2.0.4. In 1.3.7 actions seem to be closures by default, and you can set breakpoints in them and they will be honored. In 2.0.4 actions are methods by default and those can have breakpoints, but something about the new version does not allow breakpoints to be honored in closures. If you create a new action closure and try to set a breakpoint, it warns you that there is "no executable code on that line". But existing closures you get no such warning, and the breakpoints all have little red checkmarks (incorrectly) indicating that they should be honored.

Changing these to method actions seems to fix the problem. I'm sorry to whoever starred this that was probably hoping for a more general answer, I hope this helps you.

Comment: I had the exact same issue and it was driving me nuts as well !

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Grails, but I've definitely encountered this issue with Java. For me it was IntelliJ not picking up my changes and failing to re-build my project (it was running with outdated compiled code). Try cleaning your assembly directory (where ever the Grails equivalent of .class files are located) and re-building your project.

Comment: Thank you. I've force recompiles, I've even shut down IntelliJ, killed any java processes, and restarted it. Nada. The codebase is a mess, I'm on a deadline, and there's no way println is going to be enough to get it just right. Driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

I've never had issue with exact same setup (under Win7)...how about try running grails from a cmd line with debug: `grails-debug run-app` and then hooking up IDEA to debug remote on port 5005 and see if that changes anything?